# how to modify the next link in OData query result

Tags: asp.net-web-api, pagination, odata, iqueryable

I have an OData Web API service using .NET 4.5. It has a WebApi controller derived from EntitySetController:

```
public class WorkItemsController : EntitySetController<WorkItem, string>
{
    [Queryable(PageSize=100)]
    public override IQueryable<WorkItem> Get()
    {
         // go to AWS DynamoDb, get the workitems and then return
    }
}
```

As you can see, I set the server-side page size to 100. If there are more than 100 objects, the return will contain a link like:

```
<link rel="next" href="http://***/api/v1/WorkItems?$skip=100" />
```

This works fine with Microsoft SQL. But I am using DynamoDb. The "skip=100" can't be translated to DynamoDb LastEvaluatedKey. So here I want to modify the next link so it returns LastEvaluatedKey like this:

```
<link rel="next" href="http://***/api/v1/WorkItems?$skip=A12BSD123" />
```

So basically I want the ability to customize the link. So when user wants to get the next set, he/she just needs to use this link and I can get the LastEvaluatedKey from it.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the NextLink in ODataProperties of Request after applying ODataQueryOptions like below:

```
public class WorkItemsController : EntitySetController<WorkItem, string>
{
    public override IQueryable<WorkItem> Get(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
         // go to AWS DynamoDb, get the workitems and then return
         IQueryable workitems = ....;
         var settings = new ODataQuerySettings { PageSize = 100 };
         workitems = queryOptions.ApplyTo(workitems, settings);

         // Override the NextLink here
         // Get or Set Request.ODataProperties().NextLink
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Feng, thanks for your suggestion. But I don't find ODataProperties() on Request. I am using OData 5.6.

Comment: It is an extensioin method with namespace "System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions"